# What's wrong with my word count program?

Tags: c

Trying to make a function that outputs the count of words a user enters into the program. I keep getting a value of 2 with this code and I am not sure why or where I am going wrong. If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int wordcount(char string[101]){

int i, words = 0;


for(i=0;string[i] != '\0';i++)
{
    if(string[i] != '\t' && string[i] != '\0'){
        words++;

        while(string[i] != ' ' && string[i] != '\t'  && string[i] !=                       
          '\0')  
      i++;

    }

}
return words;
}




int main (void) {

char input[101];

printf("Word Counter\n");
printf("============\n");

printf("string to be analyzed: \n");
scanf("%100[^\n]", input);

 wordcount(input);

 printf(" %s - words = %i\n", input, wordcount(input));

 }
```

Comment: Well you have a debugger, don't you?

Comment: `scanf("%s", input);` :  `%s` does not include the white space. `scanf("%100[^\n]", input);` instead of.

Comment: Your `while` loop needs to check for '\0' too, not just the `for` loop.

Comment: **Always** check the result of functions if they can encounter an error like `scanf`.

Comment: code now works with BLUEPIXY's suggestion, but it only counts correctly until 2 then after that it is 1 value higher than the words inputted.

Comment: Why don't you try the other suggestions too?  As is, you don't check whether `scanf` successfully read a string, and your `while` loop will run off the end of the string unless the last char was a space or a tab.

Comment: ok, will test it out

Comment: int i, words = 0;

    for(i=0;string[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        {
        if(string[i] != ' ' && string[i] != '\t'){
        words++;
        while(string[i] != ' ' && string[i] != '\t' &&string[i] !='\0')
                i++;
        }
        }
    return words; 
    }

Comment: tried that out as you suggested, but there is still a 1 off error

Comment: only after 2 words though

Comment: You're increment `i` in two places.

Comment: Add `if (!string[i]) break;` after the `while` loop?

Comment: ahhh you are right.... will have to see what one causes the problem. thanks

Comment: The code above is giving me an off by 1 error still, should i have a comparison variable to i that i test? instead of incrementing i twice?

Comment: it works if i have "return words - 1"..... but i don't think that is good coding?

Comment: `if(string[i] != '\t' && string[i] != '\0'){` It was worse because not checked `' '`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem now is there are two.

1. `if(string[i] != '\t' && string[i] != '\0'){` deterioration, changing for the worse
2. `i` is +1 to twice in the `for` and `while`.

For example, it will change as follows.

```
int wordcount(char string[101]){
    int i, words = 0;

    for(i=0;string[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(string[i] != ' ' && string[i] != '\t'){// assuming not included the newline.
            words++;
            i += strcspn(&string[i], " \t") -1;// i point to last character of word
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

---

or `i` changes it will be in one place.

```
int wordcount(char string[]){
    int i, words = 0;
    char prev =' ';

    for(i=0;string[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(isspace(prev) && !isspace(string[i])){//isspace in <ctype.h>
            words++;//count front edge
        }
        prev = string[i];
    }
    return words;
}
```